# Seccurity Market Line and beta value?

Tags: expected-value, finance, variance

A market's return is $R_M = 0.1$ and its standard deviation is $0.175$.The risk free rate of return is $r_f = 0.03$.

A portfolio $P$ has an expected return of $0.13$ and an expected $\beta$ value of $1.8$.

How do I deduce whether or not this portfolio lies on the Capital Market Line?

I know that the equation of the SML is given by $$R_P = r_f + \frac{R_M - r_f}{\sigma_M} \times \sigma_{P}$$

Do I just check if both sides of this equation are equal? If so, how would I deduce the standard deviation of the portfolio?

Comment: Yes just plug in values. Why no beta in your SML?

Comment: Well, that's actually the formula for CML which does not directly use beta? Note, beta = 
 rho * ( σp / σm ) where rho is the correlation between portfolio and market return. So, if you know rho then u can deduce portfolio std. deviation. My hunch though is the problem is simpler - r u sure you've included everything? Is question really about CML or SML?. They are not the same.